# mailto links, gnome-gmail and chrome

Tags: gnome, email

I'm trying to get it so i can click on complex mailto links (that have params for subject etc) in a page in Chrome, and that opens the mail in gmail, in Chrome.

I've installed `gnome-gmail`.
Chrome is set as my default browser, in System/Preferences/Preferred Applications.  my `x-www-browser` and `gnome-www-browser` config are both set to `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       auto mode`:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser 
There are 3 choices for the alternative x-www-browser (providing /usr/bin/x-www-browser).

  Selection    Path                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/firefox                40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/opera                  200       manual mode

$ sudo update-alternatives --config gnome-www-browser 
There are 3 choices for the alternative gnome-www-browser (providing /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser).

  Selection    Path                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/firefox                40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/opera                  200       manual mode
```

When i open gnome-gmail, it opens in Firefox, not chrome.  Various other apps seem to prefer to open firefox rather than chrome.

When i click on a mailto, it opens an empty window in chrome.

I'm confused.  Am i missing some config here?

Any help much appreciated!  Max

EDIT:  i've now made it so that all the apps which used to open firefox (including gnome-gmail) now open chrome instead, by editing `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` and changing all instances of `=firefox.desktop` to `=google-chrome.desktop`.  So, gnome-gmail now opens chrome.  But, when i click on a mailto it still just opens a new empty chrome window.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so maybe this was a bit of a waste of time since the solution has nothing to do with gnome-gmail or the default browser, but i found the answer so i'm putting it up here in case anyone else finds it useful.

It's actually as simple as clicking the "double-diamond" icon in chrome's address bar, in gmail, and choosing the "Allow chrome to open email links" option.

http://www.thegooru.com/how-to-open-email-mailto-links-in-gmail/